# Elasticsearch Linux user

Tags: elasticsearch

I installed an Elasticsearch 7 on CentOS 7 using rpm file. After install, elaticsearch user and group is created, user which can't be used to manage elasticsearch (no login) but from what I saw will own es data directory. I don't want to manage elasticsearch with root user. Should I create a new user for that or to modify elasticsearch user? What will be the best approach?

Thank you!

Comment: Well in such case i found installing from archive works good. You can install anywhere in user space.

Comment: I still want to install using rpm, for me is more structured and easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

I found that, after elasticsearch is started, another user is created (elastic), owner of the elasticsearch process. This user can by added to the sudoers file and can by used to start/stop elasticsearch. But, I think  the best partice is to use other user for that, added in sudoers, of cource.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).